# 16.04 Ubuntu Software starts partially, closes after a couple of seconds

Tags: 16.04, software-center

Ever since 16.04 there has been nothing but issues with the new software center. First, it couldn't install anything of its life dependent on it requiring a separate package installer to be used. 
Now,  suddenly, out of the blue, ubuntu-software will not open; it loads somewhat, then force closes within a few seconds after opening. I wish these things would all be working properly before releasing a LTS. It's a little embarrassing, really. Never had these issues with 14.04.

Anyway, here's what the terminal spits out when launching from there. Help?

```
shantelle@G505:~$ ubuntu-software

(ubuntu-software:15531): Gs-WARNING **: Failed to create permission org.freedesktop.packagekit.trigger-offline-update: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Error.Failed: Action org.freedesktop.packagekit.trigger-offline-update is not registered

(ubuntu-software:15531): Gs-WARNING **: Failed to create permission org.freedesktop.packagekit.trigger-offline-update: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Error.Failed: Action org.freedesktop.packagekit.trigger-offline-update is not registered

(ubuntu-software:15531): Gs-WARNING **: Failed to create permission org.freedesktop.packagekit.trigger-offline-update: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Error.Failed: Action org.freedesktop.packagekit.trigger-offline-update is not registered

(ubuntu-software:15531): Gs-WARNING **: Failed to create permission org.freedesktop.packagekit.trigger-offline-update: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Error.Failed: Action org.freedesktop.packagekit.trigger-offline-update is not registered

(ubuntu-software:15531): Gs-WARNING **: Failed to create permission org.freedesktop.packagekit.trigger-offline-update: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Error.Failed: Action org.freedesktop.packagekit.trigger-offline-update is not registered

(ubuntu-software:15531): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_dir_read_name: assertion 'dir != NULL' failed

(ubuntu-software:15531): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_width: assertion 'GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(ubuntu-software:15531): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_cairo_surface_create_from_pixbuf: assertion 'GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(ubuntu-software:15531): Gtk-WARNING **: Error loading image 'file:///usr/share/gnome-software/featured-transmission.png': Error opening file: Too many open files

(ubuntu-software:15531): GLib-ERROR **: Creating pipes for GWakeup: Too many open files

Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. I went to 'System Settings->Details' and clicked on 'Install Updates', and now life is better.